# Update $scope values not working on screen

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having very annoying problem with my ASP.Net MVC / Angular application.

So, I have `div` that displays first name and last name of an employee:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in supervisors | limitTo:1" ng-show="!svElements" class="item_list">{{x.supervisorfName}} {{x.supervisorlName}}</div>
```

`svElements` defined in the scope as `falls` by default, so this `div` is visible.

And then I have a link, that link will hide the name and display a listbox `select tag` that show also list of names (concatenated first and last name).

```
<div ng-show="!svElements"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="toggle()">Edit</a></div>
```

When I click on the link, it will just call a `toggle` function that will make `$scope.svElement = !$scope.svElement`... In other word, it will hide the div and display the list below:

```
<div ng-show="svElements">
<select ng-model='svFullName' ng-selected='svFullName'>
    <option ng-repeat="z in supervisorsList">{{z.supervisorfName + " " + z.supervisorlName}}</option>
</select>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateUserSupervisor(x, z)">Save</a>
```

In my Angular controller, I first bring the name of the supervisor:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisor')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisors = response.data;
        $scope.svFullName = response.data[0].supervisorfName + " " + response.data[0].supervisorlName;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

The above code calls the below MVC method:

```
public JsonResult GetSupervisor()
    {
        User userData = (User)Session["user"];            
        var db = new scaleDBEntities();
        var superid = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userData.Id)
                  .Select(u => u.usrSupervisor)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
        int superid_int = int.Parse(superid.ToString());
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          where userObj.Id.Equals(superid_int)
                          select new
                          {
                              supervisorId = userObj.Id,
                              supervisorfName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                              supervisorlName = userObj.usrLastName
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );            
    }
```

And then, from my angular controller I bring the list of supervisors

```
$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisorsList')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisorsList = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

Again, the above code calls the below MVC method:

```
public JsonResult GetSupervisorsList()
    {
        User userData = (User)Session["user"];
        var db = new scaleDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          where userObj.Id != userData.Id
                          select new
                          {
                              supervisorId = userObj.Id,
                              supervisorfName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                              supervisorlName = userObj.usrLastName
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
    }
```

When I click on save to update the supervisor, the below angular code works:

```
$scope.updateUserSupervisor = function (x, z) {
    $http.post('/Home/UpdateUserSupervisor', { svId: $scope.selectedSVID })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.users = response.data;
            x.supervisorfName = z.supervisorfName;
            x.supervisorlName = z.supervisorlName;
        })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
    $scope.svElements = !$scope.svElements;
}
```

My issue is: Why I am not able to reset/update the div value in the top that contain first and last name after updating the supervisor???

Everything works fine, but when I save, it should update the displayed name without refreshing the page??

Comment: add $scope.$apply() after http success response. .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisorsList = response.data; **$scope.$apply() ;**
    })

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed

Comment: What are `x` and `z` here? `<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateUserSupervisor(x, z)">Save</a> `